# Scroll list to the bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I use a Partial View on the page and dynamically filled list.
The list height is restricted and added vertical scroll.
How to scroll the list in `JavaScript`? I tried to do it this way but no it still does not scroll.

If I use ScrollView2() - it works, but if I use refresh and ScrollView2 - it returns to the top of list

```
@model List<string>
@*<div class="row">*@
<div id="viewResults">
<div class="col-md-12" style="height:200px;overflow-y:scroll">
        <ul>
            @foreach (string logRecord in Model)//ViewBag.Logs)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(logRecord))
                {
                    <li class="listclass" style="color:blue;">
                        @logRecord
                    </li>
                }
            }
        </ul>
        <a name="LogBottomAnchor" id="LogBottomAnchor"></a>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function RefreshLog()
{
    var url = '@Url.Action("RefreshLogs", "Home")';
    $('#viewResults').load(url);
    ScrollView2();
};
function ScrollView2() {

    items = document.querySelectorAll(".listclass");
    last = items[items.length - 1];
    last.scrollIntoView();
}[/SRC]

    window.onload = RefreshLog;
</script>
```

Comment: Seems like you want to scroll the `div.col-md-12` instead of the `html` or `body`.

Comment: Use this webAPI https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: 2 Kryptur : yes, by fact I need to scroll the list, it is in the div, will try

Comment: 2 Kryptur: tested, does not scroll the list

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the function

```
 $('#viewResults').load(url);
```

is async. And the correct way is:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("RefreshLogs", "Home")';
$('#viewResults').load(url, ScrollView2);
```